# Will (LiPo) batteries draw current/voltage between packs if main lead is disconnected?

Tags: lipo, series

Never learned this stuff in school (electrician study) oddly enough.
But if you serial up 4 batteries (3S LiPo's x4 to be specific), and you switch off the main leads to the power bank..

Will the batteries still draw/distribute load in between each other?
I know the loop is broken but for some reason the one thing that got stuck in my head is that batteries - lead will always try to balance out it's internal overcapacity of electrons vs protons, and if one pack has more protons and still have a negative lead connected to it's positive, will those two packs balance each other out?

I apologize for the *noobish* question, but it's out of concern for battery safety!

[image]

Comment: Ignore the electrons and protons, they will mislead you. Current only flows if you have a complete loop.

Comment: @pjc50 Awesome, even in between battery-packs? Just worried that one pack will some how unload to it's neighbor and cause a pack to go below 3.2v (even tho in theory that should never happen as long as the lowest voltage pack is above 3.2 AND the above would be a problem).

Comment: @pjc50 Also noticed my title was misleading, used the word "current" when in fact it's the voltage i'm afraid of. Again, i'm no expect on this and I apologize!

Comment: @Torxed In this case the difference between current and voltage isn't that relevant. A change in voltage on a battery or capacitor can only come from current flow, so if there's no current, there can be no voltage change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With just the batteries? Nope. Current can only flow if the loop is closed.

BUT!

With LiPo batteries there is often a control board, they will at least still use a tiny amount of power (in the order of micro amperes usually). Some more advanced technologies can actually actively balance cells while in use or while charging, Linear had a nice chip that does that. In such a case a little while after you switch it off, it may keep currents flowing around between the batteries to balance them for a tiny while after. But those packs will be very rare.

So simply put: If there's electronics in there, anything could be happening, if there isn't, then loop broken means no current anywhere, ever. Although with LiPo it's very smart to have electronics at least for per-cell protection.

(Except for a battery's inherent self-discharge, but that's a current that flows inside each cell, so that still doesn't affect other cells in the chain and that is extremely low for Lithium types.)

Comment: Awesome! Assuming this is correct (which I will), I can now keep on building my project and sleep at night knowing my hobby project won't burn up in my sleep ^^ Just gotta get another question answered but i'll create a new question for that since they're a bit different :)

Comment: @Torxed No worries. They will be fine as long as you treat them well when you're using them.